# Can't access AEM instance on AWS EC2 through public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port, aem

Since I'm pretty new in this area, may I have ask for your wisdom about why I can't access the AEM instance through public IP? Below is what I did:

1. Installed Adobe AEM to the EC2 instance
2. Made sure that I can access AEM through localhost:4502
3. In the Security Groups section, under Inbound tab, the rule is All traffic with all ports.
4. So I tried to access the AEM through http://(IPv4 Public IP):4502
   But I received the error message:

   The connection has timed out The server at (IPv4 Public IP) is taking too
   long to respond. The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try 
   again in a few moments. If you are unable to load any pages, check your 
   computer’s network connection. If your computer or network is protected by a 
   firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Am I missing anything or did anything wrong? Please let me know if you have any idea how I should access the AEM through public IP. Thank you very much!!

Comment: could you run `netstat -ntpl` and paste the output here.

Comment: I don't think this is something to do qith AEM. This looks like AWS routing issue. Are you using ELB or route 51 etc.?